# Connection from a signal to a slot returns false

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qobject

I have the following class declaration:

```
class nets_list : public QDockWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QListView * files;

public slots:
    void SelectNet(QModelIndex i);

signals:
    void NetSelected(QString t);

public:
    nets_list(QWidget * parent = nullptr);
};
```

At some point in my `nets_list` constructor, I want to connect a `clicked(QModelIndex)` signal of the `files` member to the `NetRunner(QString)` slot in the parent of my class:

```
bool x1 = connect(files, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(SelectNet(QModelIndex)));
bool x2 = connect(this, SIGNAL(NetSelected(QString)), parent, SLOT(NetRunner(QString)));
```

The code for `SelectNet()` is just:

```
void nets_list::SelectNet(QModelIndex i)
{
    emit NetSelected(fs->fileName(i));
}
```

because I just want to extract a `QString` from the `QModelIndex` parameter so that I can call the slot in the parent class.

The problem is that the second `connect` call returns false (`bool x2` appears to be false). Why?

Also: is there a better solution for connecting signals and slots with different parameter types? I thought that using an "intermediate" function such as my `SelectNet(QModelIndex)` slot was a good solution.

**EDIT:**

the parent class is

```
class MW : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QMenu * net_menu;
    QMenuBar * menu_bar;

    QStackedWidget * ctrl;
    netBuilderWidget * builder;
    netTrainerWidget * trainer;
    netRunnerWidget * runner;

    nets_list * nets_dock;

public slots:
    void netBuilder();
    void netTrainer();
    void netRunner(QString t);

    void addNet();

public:
    MW();
    QSize minimumSizeHint() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QSize sizeHint() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};
```

Comment: I don't see no `NetRunner` slot in any `parent`? I think you need to post more code.

Comment: Does your parent have a public slots member-function called NetRunner()?

Comment: Yes, it has a `public slots: void netRunner(QString t);` declaration after a `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: @Thomas `parent` is a pointer to the parent object (i.e. the object that has a `nets_list` object in its members).

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to cast the parent to your own class (instead of QWidget) before the connection.

Comment: Saying something doesn't make it so. Maybe you spelled it wrong, just like in the comment, or there is something else wrong. How are we to know?

Comment: Just see the debug output. In such cases it prints while the signal is not connected to the slot.

Comment: @Thomas I've added the declaration of the parent class.

Comment: @AlexanderVX actually I've never worked with Qt Creator.. anyway I'll try, because using QDebug from the command line seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
SLOT(NetRunner(QString))
```

with

```
SLOT(netRunner(QString))
```

and the connect should work.

Comment: Just noticed. Thank you and sorry for the silly mistake..

Answer (score 4):

It's Qt 5, you should be using new connect syntax that would catch such issues at compile time.

Your code should read:

```
// C++11
auto conn = connect(this, &nets_list::netSelected, parent, &MW:netRunner);
// C++03
QMetaObject::Connection conn = connect(this, &nets_list::netSelected, parent, &MW:netRunner);
```

Note that `conn` is not a `bool`, although it can be used in a context that expects one.

> is there a better solution for connecting signals and slots with different parameter types?

Yes. C++11 lambdas. E.g., suppose you wanted to connect `void Source::aSignal(int)` to a `QLabel::setText(QString)` (ignoring `QLabel::setNum` for a moment):

```
connect(source, &Source::aSignal, this, [this](int param){
  label.setText(QString::number(param));
});
```